# Package helper libraries with my library C++

Tags: c++, cmake, project, lib, filetree

I am writing a library that uses other libraries which I have included in my header files due to templates. I am using CMake for a build system, and the helper libraries are kept as submodules in the `external` directory. I want to provide the user access to header files of these libraries so the user can do `#include <mylib/helperlib/helper.h>`. How do I arrange my project tree to achieve this? Also, How do I integrate it with CMake to generate install targets?

This is my project tree.

```
.
├── examples
├── external
├── include
├── res
└── src
```

Links:

[This](https://github.com/mansoormemon/cbrainx) is my library.

[libfmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) is the library I want to package with my project.

P.S. Helper libraries are not necessarily header only.

Comment: you might want to investigate conan or vcpkg, they might make your life easier

Comment: Why do you want to prefix third-party headers with your own directory? That's a weird thing to ask for. If everybody did this, you'd have a bunch of different ways of including the same header.

Comment: I am using that library in my header files. Is there a way to access those headers after installation?

Comment: You should be using the library as usual, and it should be installed alongside your library.  I'm not familiar with CMake though.